# Windows 8 metro app - can’t load remote web content in the local context

Tags: jquery, windows, sdk, microsoft-metro

I keep getting 
APPHOST9601: Can’t load http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js. An app can’t load remote web content in the local context

Mind you im only 14, Totally new to this. Just tinkering around trying to make something.

I've searched around and cant find a solution.
The project is a tracker that pulls data from bter.com api and displays. Nothing fancy.
On normal index.html works amazing. Windows 8 app, cant for the life of me get it to work :(. I've been at this just laying things out in a normal index.html file, Now with the app im almost to quits.
Heres my code - home.html file

Update: Seems i may have figured it out.
Created new .js file, added script, called it and everything is displaying nice. So it seems. Knock on wood. - Still open to any help / support you may offer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>homePage</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/pages/home/home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/pages/home/home.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
    <div class="fragment homepage">
        <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
            <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle">Welcome to App1!</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            Current Exchange Rate: <div id="ticker1"></div>


                $(function () {
                    startRefresh();
                });

                function startRefresh() {
                    setTimeout(startRefresh, 10000);
                    var turl = 'https://bter.com/api/1/ticker/doge_btc';
                    $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(turl) + '%22&format=json', function (data) {
                        jQuery('#ticker1').html(data['query'].results.json.last);
                        jQuery('#ticker1').append(' DogeCoin');
                    });
                }

            //blah ignore after
            <button id="buttonYouWantToClick">Button</button>
<div id="result"></div>



        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 doesn't allow apps to load remote web content in the local context. So you should download the Jquery file and then add it in your code.
And huh always use jquery 2.0 or above version in windows 8 app development because the previous versions doesn;'t support windows 8 app cause it conflict with Winjs.
For successfully runing your jquery in your code read this article. It was  very helpful to me too. I hope it helps

http://mywindows8apps.com/2012/10/27/how-to-use-jquery-in-a-windows-8-application/

Comment: Jquery 2.1 causes HTML1701 - Unable to add dynamic content error. So you need to use just jquery 2.0.x.